# Can I put viewpager inside a fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I'm wondering can I put a viewpager which consist 13images inside a fragment that I created?

I've created an app now that consist 7 fragment tabs with each of them showing their own images,webview,and some content in each of their fragments.

So now I have a problem,in 1-3 of the tabs I need to put in a slideshow of images parse from json,I was wondering if its possible to use viewpager to show those images and putting it inside the fragment of my tabs.

---

### UPDATE 12/12/2013

okay,after few days of trying I came up with this code.Unfortunately it doesn't work as I plan.Originally I used asynctask to load the json parsing for the images on a diff project.When I try to combining the json project with my fragment project,I removed the asyctask as I dont know how to implement together.Below is my code and error,**I am aware that the network IO is trying to access main thread** but I dont know how to solve it.Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);  
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    FragmentTabHost tabHost = (FragmentTabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    tabHost.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), R.id.realtabcontent);
    //1
    tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("Highlight").setIndicator("Highlight"), 
                  AppleFragment.class, null);
         ...
    //4
    tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("Gallery").setIndicator("Gallery"), 
                  GalleryFragment.class,  null);
```

**GalleryFragment**

```
public class GalleryFragment extends Fragment{
    private ViewPager mPager;
    private PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRetainInstance(true);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pager, container,false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        mPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mPagerAdapter = new CustomPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
        mPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
        mPager.setCurrentItem(0);
    }
```

**ViewPagerPageFragment**

```
public class ViewPagerPageFragment extends Fragment{

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_page,container,false);
}

    // url to make request
    private static String url = "http://vina.harvestcamasu.com/vina/xml/image.json";

    // JSON Node names
    static String TAG_IMAGE     = "Image";
    static String TAG_PICURL    = "PicURL";
    private String[] images = new String[13];
    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    public Drawable d1,d2,d3,d4,d5,d6,d7,d8,d9,d10,d11,d12,d13;

    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        view.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);




                try {
                    // Do something...
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
                    jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);

                    // get Gallery JSONObject
                    JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
                    // get Artist JSONObject
                    JSONObject json_gallery=json.getJSONObject("Gallery");
                    // get Image JSONArray
                    JSONObject json_artist=json_gallery.getJSONObject("Artist");


                    //getting array from image
                    JSONArray Image = null;
                    try {
                        Image = json_artist.getJSONArray(TAG_IMAGE);
                        for (int i = 0; i < Image.length(); i++) {

                            JSONObject m    = Image.getJSONObject(i);
                            images[i]       = m.getString("PicURL");


                        }
                        InputStream is1 = (InputStream) new URL(images[0]).getContent();
                        d1 = Drawable.createFromStream(is1, "src name");
                        .
                        .
                        .   
                        InputStream is13= (InputStream) new URL(images[12]).getContent();
                        d13= Drawable.createFromStream(is13, "src name");


                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }


                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return ;

            }



    }
```

**CustomPagerAdapter**

```
public class CustomPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
public CustomPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return new ViewPagerPageFragment();
}


private Drawable d1,d2,d3,d4,d5,d6,d7,d8,d9,d10,d11,d12,d13;


public void MyPagerAdapter( Drawable draw1, Drawable draw2,Drawable draw3,Drawable draw4,Drawable draw5,
        Drawable draw6,Drawable draw7,Drawable draw8,Drawable draw9,Drawable draw10,Drawable draw11,
        Drawable draw12,Drawable draw13){

    d1 = draw1;
    .
    .               
    d13= draw13;


}

public int getCount() {

    return 13;
}
public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) collection.getContext()
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    int resId = R.layout.first_page;
    View view = inflater.inflate(resId, null);

    ImageView image1 = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

    switch (position) {
    case 0:
         image1.setImageDrawable(d1);
        break;
    .
    .
    case 12:
         image1.setImageDrawable(d13);
           break;
    }

    ((ViewPager) collection).addView(view, 0);
    return view;
}

public void destroyItem(View arg0, int arg1, Object arg2) {
    ((ViewPager) arg0).removeView((View) arg2);
}

public boolean isViewFromObject(View arg0, Object arg1) {
    return arg0 == ((View) arg1);
}

public Parcelable saveState() {
    return null;
}
}
```

**Error Log**

```
12-12 14:25:08.929: E/AndroidRuntime(9185): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-12 14:25:08.929: E/AndroidRuntime(9185): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
12-12 14:25:08.929: E/AndroidRuntime(9185):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1099)
12-12 14:25:08.929: E/AndroidRuntime(9185):     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:391)
12-12 14:25:08.929: E/AndroidRuntime(9185):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:242)
12-12 14:25:08.929: E/AndroidRuntime(9185):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:220)
12-12 14:25:08.929: E/AndroidRuntime(9185):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:137)
12-12 14:25:08.929: E/AndroidRuntime(9185):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
12-12 14:25:08.929: E/AndroidRuntime(9185):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
12-12 14:25:08.929: E/AndroidRuntime(9185):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
12-12 14:25:08.929: E/AndroidRuntime(9185):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
12-12 14:25:08.929: E/AndroidRuntime(9185):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
12-12 14:25:08.929: E/AndroidRuntime(9185):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
12-12 14:25:08.929: E/AndroidRuntime(9185):     at com.tonycube.fragmenttabdemo.JSONParser.getJSONFromUrl(JSONParser.java:39)
12-12 14:25:08.929: E/AndroidRuntime(9185):     at com.tonycube.fragmenttabdemo.ViewPagerPageFragment.onViewCreated(ViewPagerPageFragment.java:56)
12-12 14:25:08.929: E/AndroidRuntime(9185):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:925)
12-12 14:25:08.929: E/AndroidRuntime(9185):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1088)
12-12 14:25:08.929: E/AndroidRuntime(9185):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
12-12 14:25:08.929: E/AndroidRuntime(9185):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1444)
12-12 14:25:08.929: E/AndroidRuntime(9185):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:461)
12-12 14:25:08.929: E/AndroidRuntime(9185):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:163)
12-12 14:25:08.929: E/AndroidRuntime(9185):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1064)
12-12 14:25:08.929: E/AndroidRuntime(9185):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:911)
12-12 14:25:08.929: E/AndroidRuntime(9185):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1432)
12-12 14:25:08.929: E/AndroidRuntime(9185):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12892)
12-12 14:25:08.929: E/AndroidRuntime(9185):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:594)
12-12 14:25:08.929: E/AndroidRuntime(9185):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:376)
12-12 14:25:08.929: E/AndroidRuntime(9185):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12892)
12-12 14:25:08.929: E/AndroidRuntime(9185):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4698)
12-12 14:25:08.929: E/AndroidRuntime(9185):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
12-12 14:25:08.929: E/AndroidRuntime(9185):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12892)
12-12 14:25:08.929: E/AndroidRuntime(9185):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4698)
12-12 14:25:08.929: E/AndroidRuntime(9185):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
12-12 14:25:08.929: E/AndroidRuntime(9185):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12892)
12-12 14:25:08.929: E/AndroidRuntime(9185):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:812)
12-12 14:25:08.929: E/AndroidRuntime(9185):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:553)
12-12 14:25:08.929: E/AndroidRuntime(9185):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12892)
12-12 14:25:08.929: E/AndroidRuntime(9185):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4698)
12-12 14:25:08.929: E/AndroidRuntime(9185):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
12-12 14:25:08.929: E/AndroidRuntime(9185):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12892)
12-12 14:25:08.929: E/AndroidRuntime(9185):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4698)
12-12 14:25:08.929: E/AndroidRuntime(9185):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
12-12 14:25:08.929: E/AndroidRuntime(9185):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12892)
12-12 14:25:08.929: E/AndroidRuntime(9185):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4698)
12-12 14:25:08.929: E/AndroidRuntime(9185):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1375)
12-12 14:25:08.929: E/AndroidRuntime(9185):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:660)
12-12 14:25:08.929: E/AndroidRuntime(9185):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:553)
12-12 14:25:08.929: E/AndroidRuntime(9185):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12892)
12-12 14:25:08.929: E/AndroidRuntime(9185):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4698)
12-12 14:25:08.929: E/AndroidRuntime(9185):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
12-12 14:25:08.929: E/AndroidRuntime(9185):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2257)
12-12 14:25:08.929: E/AndroidRuntime(9185):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12892)
12-12 14:25:08.929: E/AndroidRuntime(9185):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1240)
12-12 14:25:08.929: E/AndroidRuntime(9185):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2628)
12-12 14:25:08.929: E/AndroidRuntime(9185):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-12 14:25:08.929: E/AndroidRuntime(9185):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-12 14:25:08.929: E/AndroidRuntime(9185):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4512)
12-12 14:25:08.929: E/AndroidRuntime(9185):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-12 14:25:08.929: E/AndroidRuntime(9185):     at java.lang.reflect.M
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**: I have quickly written some example code, this code doesn't handle orientation change well. This is something you will have to figure out yourself. There a numerous ways of handling this and I'm not 100% sure what would be the most ideal. This sample code should get you started. If you figured out the correct way to handle orientation change comment below or edit this post.

**MainActivity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(android.R.id.content) == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(android.R.id.content, new ViewPagerFragment())
                    .commit();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

**ViewPagerFragment:**

```
public class ViewPagerFragment extends Fragment {

    private ViewPager mPager;
    private PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRetainInstance(true);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pager, container,false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        mPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mPagerAdapter = new CustomPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
        mPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
    }

    private class CustomPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
        public CustomPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return new ViewPagerPageFragment();
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 10;
        }
    }

}
```

ViewPagerPageFragment:

```
public class ViewPagerPageFragment extends Fragment{

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_page,container,false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        Random rnd = new Random(); 
        int color = Color.argb(255, rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256));   
        view.findViewById(R.id.fragment_page_wrapper).setBackgroundColor(color);
    }

}
```

Comment: If you have any problems or Illegalstates comment below ;)

Comment: after trying and researching for a day,I just realize getChildFragmentManager() is only usable for android 4.2 and above,and Im need it to run it at android 4.0.3 minimum.. is there any other way besides this?

Comment: You should use the support library, I'm using a viewpager inside a fragment in 2.x versions.. so it shouldn't be a problem. If you post your code I could have a look ;)

Comment: Ahh okay that was stupid of me for forgetting to include the support library,let me try again thanks a lot for the reminder!